# React Native - Custom component that is receiving state as a prop is not updating with the state

Tags: react-native

In my main component, I have a state "showDelete" defined as: `const [showDelete, setShowDelete] = useState(false)`, and I pass it to my custom component "Dropdown" like so:

```
<Dropdown
     optionStrings={optionStrings}
     error={errors.displayName}
     containerStyle={styles.dropdownInput}
     onChangeText={(text) => onChange(text)}
     value={value}
     setSelected={(newSelected)=>{selectedArray[key] = newSelected; setSelectedArray(selectedArray)}}
     selected = {selectedArray[key]}
     onDelete = {(newKey)=>{setDeleteInput(newKey);}}
     showDelete = {showDelete}
     dropdownKey={key}
/>
```

When I change showDelete in the main component using `setShowDelete(!showDelete)`, it is not updated in the Dropdown component, which receives it like so:

```
export default function Dropdown({
  optionStrings,
  containerStyle,
  onChangeText,
  inputStyle = styles.input,
  value,
  dropdownKey,
  setSelected,
  selected,
  onDelete,
  showDelete,
})
{
//a bunch of code here
}
```

If I recreate the Dropdown component whenever showDelete is changed, this will reflect the change but this is obviously not ideal. Any ideas? Also I'm pretty new to React Native in general so please let me know if I'm doing anything wrong.

Comment: Try adding key as showDelete i.e. <Dropdown key={showDelete} optionStrings={optionStrings} .... />
Or to make key more unique you can also concat some unique string with boolean like key = {id+ showDelete}

Answer (score 0):

Resolved! The issue was that I was placing my Dropdown components into an array and rendering the entire array with a map function. When I rendered the components individually, the state was passed without issue.